# Why isn't List Parts to be used with Complete Multipart Upload?

Tags: amazon-s3

The [multipart upload overview documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) has, in the *Multipart Upload Listings* section, the following warning:

> **Note**
>
> Only use the returned listing for verification. You should not use the result of this listing when sending a complete multipart upload request. Instead, maintain your own list of the part numbers you specified when uploading parts and the corresponding ETag values that Amazon S3 returns.

Why?

---

Why I ask: Let's say I want to support resuming an upload that is interrupted. Doing so means knowing what remains to be uploaded, and therefore what already was uploaded. Knowing this is simpler if I may disregard the above warning. S3 is persisting the list of already-uploaded parts. I can obtain it from List Parts.

Whereas if I heed that warning, instead I'd need to intercept break or kill signals and persist the uploaded parts list locally. Although that's feasible, it seems silly to do this if S3 already has the list.

Furthermore, the warning says to use List Parts "only for verification". OK. Let's say I persist my own list, and compare it to List Parts. If they do not match, what am I going to do? I'm going to believe List Parts -- if S3 doesn't think it has a part, of course I'm going to upload it again. Therefore if List Parts is the ultimate authority, why not simply use it in the first place, and use it alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If they do not match, what am I going to do? I'm going to believe List Parts -- if S3 doesn't think it has a part, of course I'm going to upload it again.

You're missing the point of the warning.

It's not so much about whether parts were received.  It's about whether they were received *intact*.

When you complete a multipart upload, you have to send a list of the parts and their etags.  The etags are the hex md5sum of each part.

The lazy and careless way to complete a multipart upload would be to blindly submit the etags of the parts by just reading them from the "list" operation.

That is what they are warning against.

The correct way is to use your locally-created list, based on what you think S3 should have received, what you think the etag of each part should have been, based on the local file.

If you are resuming an upload that was interrupted, you should go back and compare the parts already uploaded (by re-reading and re-checksumming the parts of the local file) against the checksums S3 has calculated against the parts already stored (as returned by the list operation)... *then* either resend any incorrect parts or missing parts, or abandon the upload because the local file may have changed if one or more parts doesn't match your local calculation.

Additionally, in the interest of data integrity, you should be sending the md5 of each part with the individual part uploads, base64-encoded, with a `Content-MD5` header, since this will cause S3 to refuse to accept a part that has been corrupted in any way during the upload.

Comment: Hmm, so maybe I'm missing the point of the warning precisely because I do provide a `Content-MD5` header for each Upload Part request. As a result, if it's in List Parts, it's intact -- or it seems to me. However maybe that's not necessarily the case. Anyway, in the normal case I provide my own parts list to Complete MUP, and wasn't planning to change that. I was considering how to support resuming interrupted uploads most simply for clients of my code. Thanks for explaining the point of the warning.

Comment: *"As a result, if it's in List Parts, it's intact"*  Yes, it is extremely unlikely for it not to be intact, in that case.  It's good to know that you are taking advantage of the integrity-checking mechanisms that S3 makes available.

Comment: The multipart utility I wrote reads through the entire file twice, calculates the etags twice, beginning the upload after the first pass and stopping if any part's etag varies on the second pass.  The first pass also allows me to calculate a sha-1 or sha-256 of the entire file, and to predict what the "xxxx-nnn"-style etag of the final uploaded object will be.  I store these as object metadata for later validation and further assurance.  Arguably, it's not optimally efficient, but data archiving is too important not to be obsessive about integrity.

Comment: Thanks for your response back in 2015. You mentioned that the ETags in the final complete request should be based on "what you think the etag of each part should have been", but S3 mentioned this in the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html): "This ETag will not necessarily be an MD5 hash of the object data." How do you calculate the ETag value if it's not guaranteed to be MD5?

Comment: @jellycsc I wish AWS would not dumb down their documentation like this, and just come right out and say that it's not the MD5 of the raw payload when the object is encrypted using a KMS key.  Otherwise it is.  This strategy works when encryption is disabled or uses SSE-S3, but not with SSE-KMS.  And in that case, you unfortunately can't calculate it, which is one of several compelling reasons to avoid SSE-KMS without extremely careful consideration.  See also https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1035

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for your response. I wish AWS can include the ETag algorithm in their official doc.